# Measuring the time spent by batches in a system in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

In a process where a batch is being unbatched, then batched again several times while preserving the batch size, how can you measure the time spent by that batch in a certain flowchart. Using "timeMeasureStart/End" is not working given that when the agent is unbatched and batched, it's like a new agent is created from scratch.
Also trying to add start and end time variables for the batch agent type is not working because after being unbatched and then batched again, variables are reinitialized. To demonstrate this, I added four images below.

[Flow Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGnBJ.png)

[Batch Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13g7J.png)

[Batch1 Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBrmW.png)

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWMYh.png)

Here is the model download link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a7550e58151c3ee38b16ceb27281c48220200713170914/2e6da6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to resolve the issue. Since each time the batch is unbatched the variables are re-initialized to 0, the solution is to inherit the start time to the unbatched agents. So in the image below, both batch and element agent types would have a variable called "start". The batch type would additionally have a variable called "end".

[Process Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwZKL.png)

Accordingly, the following code is needed:

- Block "batch" On Exit: batch.start = time();
- Block "unbatch" on Exit: agent.start = batch.start; (the elements are inheriting the start from the batch)
- Block "batch1" On Add: batch.start = agent.start; (unlike the previous block, the batch is inheriting the start time from the elements)
- Block "batch1" On Exit: batch.end = time();

This way we'll have the start time of the batch in the process and the end time which will allow us to calculate the duration of that batch in the system without having its variables reset every time it is unbatched.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the code blocks inside the `Batch` and `Unbatch` elements you use.

Create a variable in your agent being batched/unbatched, such as `totalTime`. Also a variable measuring the individual time it spends in operation like `currentTimeBatching`.

Then, add them individually as needed, maybe like:
[image]

(Specifics depend on your model setup, this is the general way to do this)

Comment: Thanks Ben. But the issue is once unbatched and batched again, the agent (batch) variables are reset. So "batch.batchBegins" value would change to 0 after the batch is unbatched. Or is there anything wrong I am doing causing this?

Comment: There is a setting for disabling making batches permanent. So unbatching returns your original agents that were batched. Make sure you use a custom agent type for these and they should remember :)

Comment: What I did is exactly the following:
1. Process: source > batch > delay > unbatch > delay > batch > sink (permanent batch is unticked)
2. Agent type:X with "start" and "end" as agent variables
3. On Exit of the first batch "batch.start = time()" and On Exit of the second batch block "batch.end = time()" in addition
4. I added variables in main to track the values
5. start = 0.663; end = 1.532, yet the the difference between agent.end - agent.start = end, so start value is being disregarded. I know the start value because I added a variable called start in main that takes the same value

Comment: not following anymore, can you re-phrase your original question and link to some screenshots as well? Show what is where, what is going wrong, what you tried already... too confusing otherwise :)

Comment: Apologies for confusing you. I updated the question with images, I hope the issue is now clearer.

Comment: cool, thx. Are you measuring start & end time in your Lote agent type? It doesn't matter what you do on main, each new batch agent will overwrite that stuff. You must measdure inside the Lote agent type only (and they report back to). Try to use tracelns for each agent flowing through...

Comment: I understand that Benjamin. I added the variables in main to compare the results. My issue is simply that once unbatched, the variables in Lote are being disregarded. Referring to my flowchart image, my goal is to measure the time from batch exit to batch1 exit. Using your suggested method which is to add variables for the agent type did not work, because once unbatched the recorded start time in the batch block is reinitialized to 0 once it reaches the block batch1. Anyway, I guess it's just not possible.

Comment: can you upload the example model you describe and share a link? Happy to have a look, should be possible :)

Comment: Thanks for your continuous follow-up. I will attach the model to the question.